# Question about editing an answer

Tags: discussion, editing

Sometimes (for no particular reason), I have add my first name (Kevin) to the end of questions or answers that I have posted.

In one particular case, I have posted an answer to a question, months ago.

Recently, someone edited this answer by simply removing my name from the end of the answer.

In part, this is odd because I have tried to edit a post with removing only a few characters from the post but the system would not allow me to save the edit because the edit was considered too minimal.

So I was wondering if it considered appropriate to put your name at the end of your answer... 
Sometimes ?, Never ?, Anytime ?

Also, is it reasonable for this editor to get credit for this sort of minimal edit ?

Comment: You get "Too minimal" if you try to change less than 6 characters. Removing your name and an empty line would be exactly 6 chars, so the system would be OK with that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Never add signatured or taglines](https://superuser.com/faq#signatures).

We welcome edits of posts of any age, there are even [badges as reward for editing older posts](https://superuser.com/badges/118/archaeologist). So it's not like those are an excepted from the [collaborative editing](https://superuser.com/faq#editing) on the site.

---

The user in question does not yet have editing privileges, the [suggestion has been approved by two more experienced users](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/73348) (and rejected by one).

While edits generally should be substantial and address multiple issues, the post in question looks good otherwise IMO, so I'd consider this edit acceptable.

Comment: I disagree, @DanielBeck. My edits use to be rejected for removing a tag line, and I feel it is VERY small for an edit

Comment: @Luke It *is* a very small edit (and one reviewer of three rejected for that reason as well), that's why I mentioned that in this case, I saw nothing else wrong with the post. When I reject for *too minor*, then there usually *are* other issues to be fixed.